# Syntax error on webdriver-manager 10.2.9

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

Post from [issue #170](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/170):

After updating to the newest version, I get the following error on running 'webdriver-manager' command.

```
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cli\logger.js:66
info(...msgs) {
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object. (C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\we
bdriver-manager\built\lib\cli\index.js:8:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is this happening? Version 10.2.9 requires node 6 and since it did not follow semantic versioning / caused a big problem, it was unpublished from npm and 10.2.10 has been published. To read more about 10.2.10, see the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

If you have encountered this issue, please remove the `node_module/webdriver-manager` and do a fresh `npm install`.

Comment: Not sure if this works. I remember internet breaking a couple of months ago because of someone unpublishing a vital package. Since then npm is not supporting that kind of unpublishing. I still have version 10.2.9 when listing :(

Comment: I just published 10.2.10 that is the same as 10.2.8 because of caching layers like Artifcatory...will update the original answer.

Comment: This is not the solution. After npm install i downloaded webdriver-manager@10.2.9...

Comment: Please read the included comments. 10.2.9 was removed and 10.2.10 was released. You could possibly still install 10.2.9 if you have a caching layer. Also this is the answer...I have had discussions with people after I released it in the Github the issue. Simply stating this is not the solution does not help. If this is a problem, open up an issue on Github or install 10.2.10.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/170#issuecomment-274493114 mine is not working too

Answer (score 2):

You can downgrade webdriver version to 9.0 with this command:

```
npm install -g webdriver-manager@9.0
```